# Tensor smooths in gamm4

Tags: r, mixed-models, gam, mgcv, splines

I am trying to extend a model similar to the one described by Gavin Simpson here to also include random effects. 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/how-to-include-an-interaction-term-in-gam

Where `loc`is replaced by a 4-level factor. The fixed effects are two categorical variables (A and B) and two continuous ones (C1 and C2) with all pairwise interactions. The response is 1s and 0s.

e.g.

```
gamm4(y~A*C1 + A*C2 + B*C1 + B*C2    
                s(yDay, bs = "cc", k = 12) + 
                s(yDay, bs = "cc", by = A, k = 12, m = 1) + 
                s(Hour, bs = "cc", k = 12) + 
                s(Hour, bs = "cc", by = Loc, k = 12, m = 1) +
                t2(Hour, yDay, by = A, bs = rep("cc",2)),
                random = ~ (1 | ID),
                family = "binomial"(link="logit"),
                data = dat)
```

Trying to run it I got the error
`Error in X %*% diag(diagU[indi]) : non-conformable arguments`

From lurking around in the code of `gamm4()` and `gamm()` it seems to be related to penalising the smooths within each level of the random effect?

I am currently running the model with a subset of 4 individuals (can end up around 40), and should also eventually nest individuals within years.

It could be that my problem is to situation specific (read: I am being way too ambitious on behalf of my data), but reading that `gamm4()` is still "construction phase" on some matters makes me wonder if I am being to ambitious on behalf of `gamm4()`?

Or I am probably just plain wrong and off hiking in some dead ends...